# "bad substitution" from ${$1:-"world"}

Tags: shell

Here my script:

```
recipient=${$1:-"world"} echo hello $recipient!
```

my console returns me:

> bad substitution

I can t figure out why since it seems to me I have followed all the recommendation for a regular substitution,

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: `${1:-"world"}`, not `${$1:-"world"}`; take out the extra `$` on the inside.

Comment: Not related to the question you asked, but as an aside, note also that the value of `recipient` is just discarded here, as `var=value somecommand` sets `var` to `value` in the environment of `somecommand`, but `echo` doesn't pay attention to `recipient` to modify its behavior in any way.

Comment: To address Charles comment: you want `echo hello "${recipient:=${1:-world}}"`

Comment: (Maybe -- I don't see a statement of what the OP's expected output is, so making any kind of presumption would be... well, *presumptuous*).

Comment: Ahh! With the code clarified, the `${var:=value}` form should indeed work; or they could just put a `;` between the assignment and the `echo`, to split them into two separate commands.

Comment: Yes, I would probably just do `echo ${1:-world}`!  @Webwoman The snippet I posted above is equivalent to `if test -z "$recipient"; then recipient="${1:-world}"; fi; echo "$recipient";`, so maybe not quite what you want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes that was a typo that I have entered in the code when I translate the original code to the snippet mode's code, now there is the original code indeed, thanks for having spotted that :).